# Always show the file extension inside the folder using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Currently, I am working on an application that will need to always show the file extensions of the files inside the folder.

Example:

I have a folder named `Awards` and the Contents are Images.

Contents:

[image: Folder Content]

As you can see, the file extension is hidden.

But when you click the options red boxed on the image. the file extension will be shown.

My question is, Is there a way to check the checkbox on the Image using vb.net? If it is possible? How??

Thank you and Regards,

Comment: To answer you question.  Yes, their will be a way.  What have you tried and what specifically is the problem you've encounter with your solution?

Comment: @Hursey , That's why I ask How. Sorry Sir, If I ask too much.

Comment: You can use the Registry `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]` to set this option

Comment: @MoKhalefa Can you help me with the code sir?

Comment: @LevesqueXylia - Here is how to write to registry  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303207/append-a-dwords-decimal-value-apposed-to-hexadecimal)

Comment: @MoKhalefa , Thank you! God Bless

Comment: @LevesqueXylia - You welcome, btw under the above key your target is `HideFileExt`

Comment: @MoKhalefa , Yep. I see it on the HKey Site References. Thanks by the way.